# Vet. Medicine Questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

I'd like to draw attention to [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1619/is-spaying-a-female-cat-beneficial-for-her-health).  I can't help but feel that this is more asking for medical **advice** (admittedly not for humans) rather than for medical explanations of physiology/pathology.

Currently it has no community close votes, but in its present form does the community feel it is on-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My feeling is no, it is not on-topic, although this didn't really occur to me until your question prompted me to think about it.

I'm guessing that narrowing the scope of this site is not the only motivating factor behind avoiding the topic of medical advice. It also has to do with protecting ourselves from any possible liability for a human life based in the case that bad medical advice from this site caused human injury or death.

I'm guessing that it hasn't gotten any close votes because on first encounter, it doesn't "smell" like other medical advice problems (human subjects, "should I...?", etc). But ultimately, you are correct, this is a medical advice question that should not be on-topic for this site, both for sake of scope and for sake of liability.

Answer (score 0):

the original poster here. I definitely did not ask for medical advice. If I wanted veterinarian advice, there are lots of places on the Internet where I could find it. I was interested in what the biologists have to say about the effects of spaying on cat's health, from the scientific (as opposed to medical) perspective.

I also think that before closing the question based on the perceived *intentions* of the question author, one should ask the author what their intentions were...

Comment: Hi :)  Thanks a lot for posting.  I can see what you mean and accept that the question isn't explicitly asking for medical advice.  What we have done in the past (see [here](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/q/42) and [here](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/q/139).  I'd particularly draw your attention to [this answer](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/a/142) by Mad Scientist - the first bullet point of which being similar in wording to your question title.  Would you consider making edits akin to those mentioned by Alexander Galkin in his answer to the previously linked question?

Comment: I did, is it more in line with the scope of the site now?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to edit - I'll reopen